# RST instead of ACK in third step of handshake process

Tags: networking, tcp, raw-sockets

I wrote c/c++ code runs on Ubuntu that simulate handshake process.

```
//Create a raw socket
int s = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
//some address resolution
strcpy(source_ip , "192.168.1.9");
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(1235);
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("192.168.1.6");



if (setsockopt (s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof (one)) < 0)
{
    perror("Error setting IP_HDRINCL");
    exit(0);
}



 {
    //Send the packet
    if (sendto (s, datagram, iph->tot_len ,  0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof (sin)) < 0)
    {
        perror("sendto failed");
    }
    //Data send successfully
    else
    {
        printf ("Packet Send. Length : %d \n" , iph->tot_len);
    }
}

int l;
if( recvfrom(s,buffer,4096,0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, &l)<0)
{
    perror("sendto failed");
}
//Data send successfully
else
{
    printf ("Packet recv. ");
}
printf ("Enter number to end: ");


int numm=getchar();
close(s);
return 0;
```

The code start by send SYN packet to 192.168.1.6:1235 that is runs on windows.

The SYN packet reached to 192.168.1.6:1235 correctly.

The SYN-ACK reached to Ubuntu (192.168.1.9:1234) correctly.

But RST shown in Wireshark instead of ACK.

I run netcat –l –p 1235 on 192.168.1.6

I tried all the following:

- use netcat in source machine(ubuntu) to open the same port (1234) that I used when I sent SYN.
- firewall in ubuntu disabled by default.
- I wrote a small code the let this machine to be a server on the same port(1234) that I used in  SYN.
- I updated the code the sent the SYN packet to unclose the socket unless I insert some character.

But no one solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you use raw sockets, your operating system is unaware that a connection exists, since you've essentially implemented your own TCP/IP stack and bypassed the operating system.

Your operating system sees an unsolicited packet and responds with an `RST` to indicate an active refusal to the remote system that is responding to your packets sent using raw sockets.

To get around it, use an IP address that is routed to the subnet you're on but that is **not** assigned on the machine using raw sockets so that the operating system does not respond, then transmit from it and listen for responses in a sort of "promiscuous mode". Your network card should support observing packets not destined to it and thus you can monitor traffic that is appropriately routed.

Comment: @meerah If this has solved your problem or you consider this a satisfactory answer then please mark it as such.